# mvc enable disable controls based on model list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, view

I am doing an Asp.Net Core Mvc 6 App.

I have and list of controls that represent the object of a page.

I have a class like this

```
public class RolesAccessModel
{
   public string OptionMenu { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

In this class I have several values

```
List<RolesAccessModel>lstRolesAccessModel=new();
RolesAccessModel RolesAccessModel=new();
RolesAccessModel="Button1";
lstRolesAccessModel.Add(RolesAccessModel );

RolesAccessModel RolesAccessModel2=new();
RolesAccessModel2="Button2";
lstRolesAccessModel.Add(RolesAccessModel2 );

RolesAccessModel RolesAccessModel3=new();
RolesAccessModel3="Button3";
lstRolesAccessModel.Add(RolesAccessModel3 );
```

I inherit this model in the View, where I have a lots of buttons and I have to make disable those buttons where the ID is in the Model

```
@model IEnumerable<ClientWeb.UI.Models.RolesAccessModel>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Employers";
}
    
   <button type="button"  class="col-1 btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="Button1">Button1</button>
   <button type="button"  class="col-1 btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="Button2">Button2</button>
   <button type="button"  class="col-1 btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="Button3">Button3</button>
   <button type="button"  class="col-1 btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="Button4">Button4</button>
   <button type="button"  class="col-1 btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="Button5">Button5</button>
```

I do not want to do a `foreach`(value in Model) foreach button

How can do that validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where I have a lots of buttons and I have to make disable those
> buttons where the ID is in the Model

Do you want the way like below?

**HomeController**: add a new action `DisableID` to pass the buttons  in the Model in a json list, and use ajax to get the list:

```
        public IActionResult Employers()
        { 
           List<RolesAccessModel> lstRolesAccessModel = new List<RolesAccessModel>();
            //...
            return View(lstRolesAccessModel);
        }
        public IActionResult DisableID()
        {
            var lstRolesAccessModel = new List<RolesAccessModel>()
            { 
            new RolesAccessModel{OptionMenu="Button1"},
            new RolesAccessModel{OptionMenu="Button2"},
            new RolesAccessModel{OptionMenu="Button3"}
            };
            
            return Json(lstRolesAccessModel); 
        }
```

**Employers.cshtml**: add below `<script>` , use`$(type = "button").each(function ()` to get the button ID and compare it with the list which contains the buttons  in the Model :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () { 
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/Home/DisableID", 
                    success: function (data) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
                            {    
                                $(type = "button").each(function () 
                                 {                                       
                                    if (this.id == data[i].optionMenu) 
                                    {$(this).attr('disabled', true); };                                             
                                 });                    
                             }
                        },
                  });
    });
    });
</script>
```

result:

[image]